# Invalid character value for cast specification on order of sql select

Tags: c++, sql-server

I have this data (simplified)
[image]

When I select `int1, int2, str1` in that order, I get a invalid cast error. When I select them in `str1, int1, int2` order the sql call completes successfully.

The sql call looks like this (again simplified)

```
Select int1, int2, str1 from table where int1 = ? (my variable)
```

There no actual casting of values in this call.

The code is c++ using ODBC connection of Native Client 11 to a MSSQL database.
The variables and bind columns are all static declared and of proper types an lengths (and in the order of the call when I changed the order).

I'm looking for any other ideas of how to find why it fails when I have a char value selection following an int value. The failure occurs at the SqlFetch function call (when the returned data is attempted to be loaded to the bound columns)

The non simplified query returns 140 columns of mixed types and I would like to apply a solution to the whole query.

(to note)
c++ column binds look like this are in the order of the select:

```
sqlret = SQLBindCol(hstmt_myQuery,item_col,SQL_C_LONG,&int1, (SDWORD) sizeof(int1), &indicator[item_col++]); exec_sql_error(__FILE__, &henv, &hdbc, last_connect_time, "BindCol hstmt_myQuery", hstmt_myQuery, &sqlret);
sqlret = SQLBindCol(hstmt_myQuery,item_col,SQL_C_LONG,&int2, (SDWORD) sizeof(int2), &indicator[item_col++]); exec_sql_error(__FILE__ , &henv, &hdbc, last_connect_time , "BindCol hstmt_myQuery" , hstmt_myQuery , &sqlret  );
sqlret = SQLBindCol(hstmt_myQuery,item_col,SQL_C_CHAR,str1, (SDWORD) sizeof(str1), &indicator[item_col++]); exec_sql_error(__FILE__ , &henv, &hdbc, last_connect_time , "BindCol hstmt_myQuery" , hstmt_myQuery , &sqlret  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation order of parameter are unspecified.

So you have issue with `item_col` with `SQLBindCol(/*..*/, item_col, /*..*/, item_col++);`.

increase `item_col` in a separate statement should solve your issue.